# go get not installing package k8s-oidc-helper

Tags: go, kubernetes, openid-connect

Unable to install package with go.
I want to install the k8s-oidc-helper package. As per the install guide i had to install go and run the k8s-oidc-helper command. But when i try it, it says command k8s-oidc-helper not found. Below are the commands I tried

```
sudo apt install golang-go
export $GOPATH=/usr/share/go
sudo -E go get github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper
```

But after this if i try **`k8s-oidc-helper command it says error command not found.`**
I assume it is some error with `go` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the `k8s-oidc-helper` is exists in `/usr/share/go/bin`, and `/usr/share/go/bin` has been added into PATH environment variable.

Check:

```
ls /usr/share/go/bin | grep k8s-oidc-helper

echo $PATH | grep /usr/share/go/bin
```

Comment: actually it is present under /usr/share/go/src/github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper. Could you please help. There is no bin directory

Comment: @NSP try `sudo -E go install github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper`, and then `ls /usr/share/go/bin | grep k8s-oidc-helper`.

Comment: `sudo -E go install github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper,
can't load package: package github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper,: cannot find package "github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper," in any of:
 /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper, (from $GOROOT)
 /usr/share/go/src/github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper, (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: Um, I don't know how to fix it, I install this package correctly on my Linux desktop. You can take a try, remove this package: `sudo rm -rf $GOPATH/src/github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper`, and then reinstall: `sudo -E go get -v github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper`, `-v` means that it will print the install details.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help :( -v only shows details of download. `sudo -E go get -v github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper
github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper (download)
github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper
`

Comment: The issue was with the path. I set the path to /usr/lib/go and it worked. Thanks for you help