# k8s oidc issues with helper package (k8s-oidc-helper: command not found)

Tags: go, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, openid-connect

I am facing issues with k8s-oidc-helper package installed with go. However when i run any of the commands with it it gives command not found error. I am running this on ubuntu 16.04 VM. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you asked [the same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451539/go-get-not-installing-package-k8s-oidc-helper)?

Comment: Yes. I made this question more K8S specific unlike the previous one which i assume is some error happening due to `go`

Comment: Well, the text of this question says "I have installed k8s-oidc-helper", so does that mean you are now able to execute `k8s-oidc-helper` and now have questions on how to use that command with kubernetes? Because the questions and answers on your other post make it seem as though you are unable to install `k8s-oidc-helper`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel i have restructured my question. I am not able to run any commands using k8s-oidc-helper package installed with go. As i am new to this, i am not even able to ascertain if its an error caused due to go or k8s package itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. The path set was incorrect for `go'
I checked the environment of go and accordingly set the path.

```
export GOPATH=/usr/lib/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
sudo go get -u github.com/micahhausler/k8s-oidc-helper
```

now the helper package works